# How to upload only minified JS or CSS files with FTP in IntelliJ / PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

On commit, I only want to upload minified files like `*.min.js` or `*.min.css` but not the original files.

How can I achieve that in JetBrains IDE like PhpStorm? It is done at the "Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment -> Options".

IntelliJ states they accept regex in the filter: some kind of regex could do the job, but regular regex seems not to work.

I've tried using the following regex `^(?!.*\bmin\b).*\.js$` but this is not accepted.

Any workaround on this?

Comment: Look for the field labeled 'Exclude items by name', for the regex you can try something like:
*;!?*.min.{js,css}

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa this is the filter rule:
.svn;.cvs;.idea;.DS_Store;.git;.hg;*.hprof;*.pyc;!?.min.{js,css}

TY! But the original JS and CSS files still upload and are not excluded as it seems.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-deployment-options.html It's just simple `*` for multiple symbols and `?` for a single. The "Regular-Expressions.info." link must be a mistake as far as I'm aware. P.S. I would be uploading both normal and minified versions -- it will not hurt.

Comment: @LazyOne not including the original js on the server means that it is more difficult to reverse engineer the js code. annotations are removed on the minified versions and also strings are simplified. Or do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: In this case it is much better to separate the consent: keep original files in one folder and final (minified) in another. Normally you would have something like this: `src/js` that builds into `build/js`. Another/more simpler approach is to have such folders next to each other, e.g. `assets/js/src` and `assets/js`. In both cases you exclude `src` from uploading. In other words: do not keep source and minified versions in the same folder if you do not want to have sources deployed.

Comment: Another idea: upload but restrict the web access with webserver config (`.htaccess` etc; so the file cannot be reached via web, only the actual file system access -- FTP/SSH/etc)

Comment: Protect in htaccess or even in cloud flare is a reasonable option!
Maybe IntelliJ adds FTP filtering on regex.